# Ubuntu Lagging when GPU is full but Memory/CPU Available

Tags: ubuntu, cpu-usage

My Ubuntu is lagging when the GPU shows 99%. However, there is enough memory and CPU to operate smoothly.

Please see the details below:

**GPU Usage:**

```
$ nvidia-smi 
Thu Oct 14 16:27:52 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.33.01    Driver Version: 440.33.01    CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Graphics Device     On   | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   66C    P0    90W /  N/A |   6319MiB /  7982MiB |     99%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1535      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            28MiB |
|    0      1943      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          50MiB |
|    0      3599      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           218MiB |
|    0      3755      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         156MiB |
|    0      4505      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       2MiB |
|    0      4591      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       2MiB |
|    0      4643      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       2MiB |
|    0      4992      G   ...AAgAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAA= --shared-files    38MiB |
|    0      6557      C   python3                                     5699MiB |
|    0      7146      G   ...AAgAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAA= --shared-files   110MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**CPU and Memory Usage:**

```
top - 16:30:31 up  1:37,  1 user,  load average: 2.43, 2.88, 2.56
Tasks: 467 total,   2 running, 363 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 13.2 us,  0.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 85.2 id,  0.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.8 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 32641040 total, 13042516 free, 12848156 used,  6750368 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 67108860 total, 67108860 free,        0 used. 19049248 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 6557 ravi      20   0 21.472g 7.537g 579128 R 156.2 24.2 141:14.39 python3
 3755 ravi      20   0 5812852 406344 106060 S  12.5  1.2   4:45.23 gnome-shell
 6751 ravi      20   0  557060  62464  47768 S  12.5  0.2   9:00.43 gnome-syste+
 2032 root      20   0 2067300  12724  10748 S   6.2  0.0   0:03.00 teamviewerd
 3806 ravi      20   0  356520   8856   6420 S   6.2  0.0   0:07.07 ibus-daemon
 4799 ravi      20   0  799568  40980  30108 S   6.2  0.1   0:03.70 gnome-termi+
    1 root      20   0  225744   9412   6548 S   0.0  0.0   0:08.75 systemd
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
    3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_gp
    4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp
    6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0+
```

[image]

**OS Information:**

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

$ uname -r
5.4.0-86-generic
```

**lshw -C display**

```
$ sudo lshw -C display
[sudo] password for ravi: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=nvidia latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff irq:189 memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:6050000000-605fffffff memory:6060000000-6061ffffff ioport:5000(size=128) memory:a4000000-a407ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 05
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:187 memory:6063000000-6063ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:6000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

**Is there any way to make Ubuntu work smoothly (without killing my python process)?**

Comment: I've observed this behaviour for years now. No clue how to solve it. Maybe using (a) Wayland (session) could be a solution.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov: Thank you very much for your comment. I will try Wayland soon. Right now, I suspect if the problem is due to gnome-shell and xorg. These two things are using GPU and there is not enough GPU for them to use. I am thinking if I can move these two to CPU somehow.... (just my guess)

Comment: It's not about Gnome Shell, but could be about Xorg, it happens for me when running any intense CUDA/compute applications. There similar topics posted here https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-graphics/linux/148

Comment: Isn't it simply that your python process is using the GPU which means the GPU doesn't have enough resources to paint our fancy modern GUIs? Unless you use either a very lightweight desktop environment or maybe use an onboard GPU to draw the desktop, I don't see how this could be fixable even theoretically. If you don't have enough resources, you don't have enough resources and the CPU/RAM won't be relevant if the limiting factor is the GPU.

Comment: Do you have an iGPU ? CPU and RAM cannot draw.

Comment: @terdon: Thanks for your suggestion. Can you suggest me a very lightweight desktop environment then which is easier to install? Anyway, I am not a huge fan of fancy GUI. :)

Comment: @AbdullahIbnFulan: I am not sure if it has an integrated one. Please see the output of _"lshw -C display"_ command added in the question, just now.

Comment: As far I can tell, you have. Exact model can be said from you CPU model. Use something like [PRIME](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PRIME) for display and ordinary works and you can use your GPU for intense workloads.